# Matlab Neural Network : switching from feedforward to timedelay causes constant output

Tags: matlab, machine-learning, neural-network, feed-forward

I have some code that uses Neural Networks.
When I use the non-memory feedforwardnet like that:

```
  feedforwardnet(nHidden);
```

everything works okay, I have good approximation of the function I want.

But if I switch to timedelaynet like that:

```
timedelaynet(1:1, nHidden);
```

the output of the Neural Network ie:

```
a1 = mainNet(inputsD');
```

is multiple constants; in green the target (datas to approximate) and in red the output:

[image: output]

What am I doing wrong?

Here are the other NN init code lines:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

nHidden = 3;
if (TDN)
    mainNet = timedelaynet(1:1, nHidden);
else
    mainNet = feedforwardnet(nHidden);
end
% Choose data division type:
%   'dividerand'  : Random division.
%   'divideblock' : Block division.
%   'divideint'   : Interleaved division.
mainNet.divideFcn = 'dividerand';

% Setup division of data for training:
mainNet.divideParam.trainRatio = 70/100;
mainNet.divideParam.valRatio = 15/100;
mainNet.divideParam.testRatio = 15/100;

% Choose training algorithm:
%   'trainlm'  : Levenberg-Marquardt.
%   'trainrp'  : Good for pattern recognition, bad for regression.
%   'trainscg' : Conjugate Gradient, good for larger networks.
%   'traingdx' : Variable learning rate.
%   'trainbr'  : Bayesian Regularization.
mainNet.trainFcn = 'trainlm'; 

mainNet.layers{1:1}.transferFcn = 'tansig';

mainNet.trainParam.min_grad = 1e-100;
mainNet.trainParam.goal = 1e-10;
mainNet.trainParam.epochs = 300000;
mainNet.trainParam.max_fail = 100000000;

 mainNet.trainParam.mu_inc = 4;
 mainNet.trainParam.mu_max = 1e200;
% %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```